# How to ask if foursquare is installing in the phone and how to open foursquare in android code?

Tags: android, objective-c, foursquare

I don't know how to ask if foursquare is installing in the phone and how to open foursquare.

I have this code in iPhone but now I don't know how to do in android. My code in objective-c is this:
`NSString *urlSTR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"foursquare://venues/%@", venueID];
    NSURL *openFoursquare = [NSURL URLWithString:urlSTR];
    if ( ![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:openFoursquare] ) {
        urlSTR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://es.foursquare.com/v/%@", venueID];
        openFoursquare = [NSURL URLWithString:urlSTR];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:openFoursquare];
    }`

Any idea? I hope that somebody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
try {
    startActivity(intent);          
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Activity not found, app not installed!
}
```

Or you can ask the `PackageManager` if the package is installed with the following:

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {   
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to ask pakckagename? I don´t know How to get packagename.

Comment: You can always find the packagename in the Play Store link. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joelapenna.foursquared  So the packagename of FourSquare is "com.joelapenna.foursquared"